# Creating user defined ROUND function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, user-defined-functions, sql-function

I am trying to create a user defined `ROUND` function so that it works in a different way than the standard `ROUND` function in SQL Server.

Basically what I am trying to do is if the input value is for example 80.5, I am trying to create a `ROUND` function that will round this value to 80 and not 81 (which is the output of standard `ROUND` function).

I created a query to do so and added the same code while creating the ROUND function. Below is the query that I created:

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (80.56925 - ROUND(80.56925,0)) = -0.5 THEN FLOOR(80.56925) 
         WHEN (80.56925 - ROUND(80.56925,0)) > -0.5 AND (80.56925 - ROUND(80.56925,0)) <= -0.1 THEN ROUND(80.56925,0)
         WHEN (80.56925 - ROUND(80.56925,0)) >= 0 THEN ROUND(80.56925,0)
         ELSE 80.56925 
    END
```

The output of this query is what I need.

Now I am trying to further enhance this because as you may have understood this will work only if I have 1 decimal place value that is the `ROUND` function is basically working as `ROUND(input, 0)` but I want to run this for `ROUND(input, 1)`, `ROUND(input, 2)` and so and so forth.

Now I understood that I need to pass another variable as an input parameter but I am not sure about the changes that I need to make in the above `SELECT` statement.

Any suggestions on how I may work on this and improve the `ROUND` function?

Comment: So what is the logic here, do you just want to round down when you have 0.5 instead of up? What about 0.51?

Comment: Yes.! That's what I want to do round it down instead of rounding it up when it's 0.5....The query works but only for 1 decimal place value....I want the same logic to run when it's 0.51 or 0.55 or 0.567 etc... Sorry if I haven't been clear.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, just substract 1, round, then add it back

```sql
SELECT ROUND(80.5 - 1,0) + 1 AS RoundedNumber;
```